# Не работает функция click

Tags: jquery

Версия: jquery-3.3.1

Сам код:

html:

```
<strong id="smokeweed"> +</strong>
```

js:

```
$('#smokeweed').click(function(){
    alert( "..." ); 
});
```

Кликаю по нему - не работает.
Ошибок в консоли нет.
Работает только если в консоли отправить имитацию `$('#smokeweed').trigger('click');`
А на пустой страничке всё работает, уже не знаю что делать

Помогите, пожалуйста

```js
$('#smokeweed').click(function() {
  alert("...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong id="smokeweed"> +</strong>
```

Comment: Удостоверься что событие вешается после рендеринга страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент `<strong id="smokeweed"> +</strong>` накрыт каким-то другим элементом. Щелкните по нему правой кнопкой мыши и выберите "Inspect element".

*Update*

> Поставил уже так, всё равно не работает

Не проблема. У меня еще много хороших идей.

У Вас на странице больше одного элемента с `id="smokeweed"`. Однако, выборка по `id` возвращает обертку, содержащую максимум один - первый найденный с таким `id` - элемент. Замените `id` на `class` и делайте `$(".smokeweed")` вместо `$("#smokeweed")`.

Comment: Поставил уже так, всё равно не работает http://prntscr.com/krtjnc

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!!!

Comment: @flappypappy На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Поставил, еще раз спасибо!